# Update several data bound user controls in a WPF/WCF Application

Tags: wpf, wcf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

My brain in stuck trying to resolve an issue i have encounted and some assistance would go a long way.

I have an application which downloads a data structure from a WCF service and the data is stored in an observable colletion property. I have a user control that contains a grid and is bound either on the user control initilizer or throught an `x:Static` databinding. The user control or the observable collection property can be accessed on the same machine more then once.

If I have multiple instance of the user control open and modify a record using the grid, I send the change to the WCF service which modifies the SQL database adds a few bits to the modified object and is passes it back to WPF (perhaps in future to other client apps through postbacks) app and the grid updates. However it only updates on that one particular usercontrols grid.

If I force the other user controls grid to rebind then the data change is reflected which is not what I want. So I decided to use LINQ to find the object to be modified in the observable collection, add then inserted the object to the collection using the `IList.IndexOf` to the place it was in the collection and remove the old object. Doing this method does seem to work fine but I have been reading that there is a better way of acheiving this.

Can anyone help shed some light on what I am trying to acheive or is the way that I have accomplished notifying all bound grids that a change is made the right/only of doing this all my properties implement inotifypropertychanged on there values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who hosts the ObservableCollection?

Comment: The ObservabeCollection is generated from a WCF service using data stored in an SQL db which is sent to the application and stored as a static property in a static class on the client machine as a local cached copy which the grid(s) is bound

Comment: Please provide some code. How is the collection created? How is it cahced? How are the grids bound to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The collection is created by the wcf service and handed over to a static class to provide access to it. The grids are bound to this static class.

According to your comments I have to rewrite my anser:

You have a static property the grids are bound to. If you assign a new collection to this property, the grids are still bound to the old one and therefore they do not update because from their point of view nothing changed.

If you change one item inside the the collection you changed the item and not the collection. So the bound grids wont update because fromt theit point of view nothing changed.

When you want to have the grids updated you have to register a ChangedEvent-Handler on all your collection items when they are added. Every time this handler is invoke because you changed one item of the collection you have to trigger the grids to update.

This is usually done by a view model that wraps the collection (the model). The grids then bind to this view model, which takes care of informing the grids (the views) of any change. Have a look at the MVVM design pattern which will provide you a standardized way to solve your problem.

Comment: the collection is only handed to the static property once and that is when the application MainWindow is first loaded. any time a secondary user control is loaded it is bound to the static colletion. if i make changes to to observable collection direcly then all grids bound to the same collection but if modify a record in the collection from the grid the other grids dont update. only if force it to rebind. I think i know where i am going wrong because im trying to set the item that i want to modify like this... oldObjectInObservableCollection = newObject and hope that the changes are reflected

Comment: also i noticed that if i changed the static collection proeprty to a new observablecollection even though the collection property implemetns inotifypropertychanged the grids wont show the new grid unless i rebind it to the static property

Comment: once again i can get it working if i isolate the record im trying to modify using LINQ queries. removing the record and placing the new once it its place using ILIST.IndexOf to find where it last was.

Comment: yeah i have stumbled across what you are recommending in forums and other questions but its nice to get clarification from someone with experience. I'll have to read more about how to invoke the event handler to update the grid(not sure whe and where to add the handler) but atleast i have some direction. also with the MVVM i have messed around with the ViewModelBase with mixed results but i'll have to keep working on it and perhaps how to get the Changed EventHandler to talk to the ViewModel. Thanks A billion for your time